# What on Earth does Lang mean by "write the second square in the form..." in proof of Lemma 5.2, Homotopies of Morphiphsms of Complexes?

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra, abelian-categories, injective-module, diagram-chasing

On the top of page 789 (I own the hardcopy of the book btw ;) it says:

> Next we must construct $f_1$.  We write the second square in the form
> $$
> \require{AMScd}
> \begin{CD}
> 0 @>>> E^0/M @>>> E^1\\
> & @V{f_0}VV\\
> & &  I^0 @>>> I^1
> \end{CD}
> $$

Now on the previous page we have proven (and understood the proof) that:

$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
0 @>>> M @>>> E^0 @>>> E^1 @>>> \dots \\
& & @V{\varphi}VV @V{f_0}VV\\
0 @>>> M' @>>> I^0 @>>> I^1 @>>> \dots
\end{CD}
$$

commutes, i.e. that such a morphism $f_0$ that makes the first square commute.  The overall lemma I'm trying to prove is given the above diagram (minus $f_0$), where the top row is exact and the bottom row is such that each $I^n$ is an injective object, then there exists a morphism of the two complexes $f: E \to I$ such that $f_{-1} = \varphi$ and for any two such morphisms $f,g$ of complexes, they are homotopic to one another, meaning there exists morphisms (in the ambient abelian category) $h_n : E^n \to I^{n-1}$ such that $f_n - g_n = d'^nh_{n+1} + h_{n + 2}d^{n+1}$ where $d$ is the differential for the top row (which is exact), and $d'$ the differential for the bottom row.

So what does Lang mean by "write the second square in the form ..."?

Comment: Hi, just curious, is owning the hard copy some achievement? I don’t know anything about all these topics, so I’m not trying to be sarcastic.

Comment: @insipidintegrator no, it's something to be proud of, not pirating books.

Comment: Oh, Ok! I actually though it was some classic like Principia or something, which people would show off in their libraries

Comment: @insipidintegrator that's true too.  It is a classic.  It's my bible.  I have minimal coffee stains and errata corrections in it.  All the pages are still there, it has a hard cover, and I think I'll be going through it for another five years and probably keep it as a reference for the rest of my life.  It's the bible!  I don't think you could recommend an AA book better than Lang, because there doesn't exist one?  If there does, let me know, pls.

Comment: @insipidintegrator also, if you don't know these topics, you should begin to learn them ASAP.  If you can quotient two R-modules abstractly, and know how to prove well-definedness, then you're good to start.  The arrow theoretic math in my oppinion is easier than the more analytic type math involving the actual element expressions.  Here we're dealing usually only with objects and arrows.  So if you like drawing arrows on paper, it's kind of fun!   An $R$-module is just a vector space except you can't divide by the scalars.   You can always quotient by a submodule b/c a priori it's abelian grp

Comment: @Primegaphomologystonermon. Of what book of Serge Lang do you speak… he hasn’t written only one.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net Lang's Algebra! :)

Answer (score 1):

The top row is exact so that $d^{-1} : M \rightarrowtail E_0$ is an injection.  By $E_0 / M$ he actually means $E_0 / d^{-1}(M) = E_0 /\ker d_0$.

Because we quotiented by the kernel of $d_0$, we get that the induced map ${d^0}^*: E_0/\ker d^0 \rightarrowtail E_1$ is an injection, so that we get:

$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
E_0 @>{\pi}>> E_0/\ker d^0 @>{d^0}^*>> E^1\\
@V{f_0}VV @V{f_0^*}VV @V{\exists f_1}VV\\
I^0 @>{=}>> I^0 @>{d'^0}>> I^1
\end{CD}
$$

Now you compose $g = d'^0 \circ f_0^*$ to get an injectivity triangle on the right, since ${d^0}^*$ is injective (a monic).  By definition of injectivity, there exists $f_1 : E^1 \to I^1$ making the triangle/square commute.  The square on the left also commutes by definition of induced map $f_0^*$ on the quotient.  When you paste together two commuting polygons along a common edge, the resulting diagram commutes.  Thus composing all the maps, we get that the outer rectangle commutes, which is the commuting square we're after, the second one in the sequence.